# yeoman,grunt and bower together with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, bower, frontend, yeoman

This is going to be my first big project.
The content is literally huge, so I'm looking for a envirnonment that is going to give me easy time when maintaining stuff.
I will use wordpress as CMS, and I'm not quite sure how much do I need Yeoman,Grunt and Bower.I've considered these as pretty cool and inovative in my own development.
Is that hard to keep good and consistant work considering that I'm using these for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Of those I'd say grunt is the most useful for Wordpress development, although depending on how you like to include dependencies bower is also worth considering.

For Wordpress work I have

- a 'default' grunt task, that watches my theme directory and rebuilds CSS when any SASS files change (grunt-contrib-watch also features livereload)
- a 'build' grunt task, that runs jshint and uglify on my Javascript, builds and minifies CSS from SASS, runs imagemin on my img directory, adds a cache-busting parameter to CSS/JS links, copies everything that I want to deploy to a 'build' directory
- SFTP and SCP tasks for deploying the contents of the build folder

There's more you can do, but hopefully that gives you an idea of how useful something like grunt can be. I've also used gulp, but found it offers less in the way of readily available modules. Here are the highlights of my package.json:

```
"bower": "^1.4.1",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.3",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.1",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.2",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-scp": "^0.1.8",
"grunt-sftp-deploy": "^0.2.4",
"grunt-text-replace": "^0.4.0",
```